# Access current schema context

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say we have such situation:

```
from django_tenants.utils import schema_context

def do_something(context):
    print("do_something")

def my_callable():
    tenant = "db_tenant"    
    with schema_context(tenant):
        context = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
        do_something(context)

my_callable()
```

And question is: It's possible to access current **tenant name** in `do_something` function without passing it as parameter or store it as **global** variable

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution but i don't know if it's stable. So, current **tenant** name (or **schema_name**) can be accessed through `django.db` connection as follow:

```
from django.db import connection

schema_name = connection.schema_name
```

Comment: This can be the accepted answer. With the above solution you have the schema name, with it you can query the tenant name.

Comment: AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'schema_name'

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, or at least will require some magical engineering to do so.

I'm assuming the only reason you wouldn't want to pass it as a parameter is because other things may be calling `do_something` as well that wouldn't be passing `tenant` as a parameter. In this case do:

```
def do_something(context, tentant=None):
    if tenant:
        print (tenant)
    else:
        print ("do_something")
```

Now you can call `do_something` with `do_something(context, tenant='Bob')` or `do_something(context)` and either will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but problem is not that ```do_something``` is accessed somewhere else, the problem is that schema context are lost over call stack